# Why isn't this regex outputting correctly?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want it to output `@email.com`...

```
var regex = /\u0040[\-_0-9a-za-Z]{1,65}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}/;
document.write(regex.exec("hi@email.com"));
```

Comment: Check your first range (you have a lower case 'a' which should be 'A')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change `a-Z` to `A-Z`. The case matters.